# The principal bundle of embeddings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

In a paper of [P. Michor](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/mf-smo-3.pdf), it was shown that *Emb(M,N)* is a smooth principal *diff(M)*-bundle, *M* and *N* are smooth locally compact manifolds provided *dim M < dim N*. My question is why there is a restriction on the dimensions. Does anyone know a reference for the result when *dim M = dim N* ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The link is broken for me.

Comment: Sorry, It's fixed now

Answer (score 8):

Then an open subset of $Emb(M,N)$ is $Diff(M)$. Namely, if $M$ is compact, the image of $M$ under an embedding is open and closed, so you have a diffeomorphism onto a connected component. If $M$ is not compact, there are no smooth movements in $Emb(M,N)$ tangential to the image near infinity. If $M$ is compact with boundary, see

- MR3263203 Reviewed Gay-Balmaz, François; Vizman, Cornelia Principal bundles of embeddings and nonlinear Grassmannians. Ann. Global Anal. Geom. 46 (2014), no. 3, 293–312.

Comment: I'm so grateful to have an answer from you personally, thanks